# Jquery: block onclick div action when click in other object inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I have this situation: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7ac/4/

```
$(".more").hide();

$(document).on("click", ".btn",function() { 
            alert("hello");     
});   

$(document).on("click", "div.post",function() {
     var morediv = $(this).find(".more");

     morediv.slideToggle('fast');
});
```

I need to keep ".more" closed(or open) when click in ".btn".

How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn",function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();    
    alert("hello");     
});
```

...note the `event` argument to the callback, make sure to include it as above.

http://jsfiddle.net/KJ5Uv/

Cheers

Comment: You're welcome.  If you feel I answered your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark in the upper left (if you see one).  In general, it's good practice on SO to up-vote answers you felt were helpful.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Just `return false` at the end of the `.btn` click event handler.

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn",function() { 
            alert("hello");     
    return false;
});
```

When you `return false` in a jQuery event handler it's like calling `event.preventDefault()` as well as `event.stopPropagation()` at the same time.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7ac/5/

Docs for `event.preventDefault()`: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Docs for `event.stopPropagation()`: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: Are you *sure* he wants to prevent the default behavior of the link?

Comment: I guess my point is, preventing the default behavior of the event isn't required to solve the problem and in fact may not be what op intends.  YMMV

Comment: @Madbreaks The link has a href of `#`. So unless it's a link to the top of the page, it's probably not going to use the default behavior. Honestly though, not enough information is given to really know. Lucky for the OP they have explanations of both options.